# Limit of function is a number from real numbers(not +- infinity)

Tags: limits

I have to choose which functions(on graphs) have their own limit, a is only from real numbers(not +- infinity)

[image]

I think that their own limit have functions 1 and 4; number 3 does not exist and I am not sure about number 2.

Will you help me? thx a lot :)

Comment: I would answer only the fourth one. The first one seens to go to $-\infty$; the second one is discontinuous; the third one goes to either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ and the last one is even differentiable!

Comment: @MattiP. It seems that the first one is continuous at $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, indeed both the second and the third options don't have limit for $x \to 1$ since right and left limits are different.

The first and the fourth one are continuous at $x=1$ and this guarantees that the limit exists since

$$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=f(1)$$